# Открыть диалог из рабочего потока

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему при методе `Show()` блокируется форма, а при методе `ShowDialog()` нет

Так блокируется:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Form forma = new();
        forma.Height = 500;
        forma.Width = 500;

        forma.Show();
    });
}
```

А так не блокируется:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Form forma = new();
            forma.Height = 500;
            forma.Width = 500;

            forma.ShowDialog();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Потому что вы не можете открыть форму из стороннего потока. Что именно вы собираетесь сделать, зачем это все нужно? Оба варианта выглядят страшно.

Comment: Да уж. Обычно формы заранее создают, а по кнопкам просто делают видимыми, например.

Comment: Подскажу, в конечном итоге ни одна из форм работать не будет, даже если система сможет сделать вам диалог из стороннего потока.

Comment: @aepot это тестирую и вроде как вариант forma.ShowDialog(); у меня работает (наткнулся методом тыка). А нужно мне, чтобы рабочий поток отправил команду главному потоку отобразить кастомную форму или же как то отобразить прям в нём xD В это окно пользователь должен ввести данные и эти данные нужно считать при нажатии кнопки в тот самый рабочий поток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А нужно мне, чтобы рабочий поток отправил команду главному потоку отобразить кастомную форму или же как то отобразить прям в нём xD В это окно пользователь должен ввести данные и эти данные нужно считать при нажатии кнопки в тот самый рабочий поток

```cs
Task.Run(() =>
{
    int variable = 0;
    DialogResult result = default;
    // ... работа
    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        Form2 forma = new();
        forma.Height = 500;
        forma.Width = 500;
        result = forma.ShowDialog(this);
        variable = forma.ResultVariable;
    }));
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // ... работа
    }
});
```

`this.Invoke` остановит рабочий поток, пока открытый диалог не будет закрыт.

Объявите публичные поля или свойства в открываемом диалоге или определите метод, возвращающий необходимые значения из формы. Или вообще инкапсулируйте данные в экземпляре класса для данных.

Comment: А как вызвать Invoke если всё это находится в методе другого класса ?

Comment: @Vipz передать ссылку на форму в другой класс. Сделать в форме публичный метод, принимающий `Action`.

Comment: Получается что я должен везде таскать с собой ссылку на Form1, где бы я не хотел отобразить кастомную форму  ?

Comment: @Vipz Вы можете создать отдельный синглтон-класс, какой-нибудь `DialogFactory` и вызывать ее оттуда типа `var data = DialogFactory.Instance.DataFromScreen("MyDialog")`. Там уж как вам хочется это запроектировать, так и проектируйте. Советую поизучать шаблон проектирования MVP, если для форм.

Answer (score 1):

> А нужно мне ... отобразить кастомную форму ... В это окно пользователь должен ввести данные и эти данные нужно считать при нажатии кнопки в тот самый рабочий поток

То есть на время показа формы вычисления в потоке прекращаются до тех пор, пока не будут введены данные. Следовательно, это можно реализовать как-то так:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // какие-то вычисления                
});

Form forma = new();
// ...

Task.Run(() =>
{
    // продолжение вычислений
});
```

Вот как это может выглядеть реально:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var partialResult = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
    {
        return 42;
    });

    var form = new Form();
    var nud = new NumericUpDown { Parent = form };
    form.Text = partialResult.ToString();
    form.ShowDialog();

    var value = (int)nud.Value;

    var result = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
    {
        // продолжение вычислений
        return partialResult * value;
    });

    Text = result.ToString();
}
```